# How to group by week use sunday based week

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to extract grouped data for the week using postgresql. Using sunday as the starting day of the week.

The main problem is how to make the week count from Sunday instead of Monday

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087376/group-by-week-and-week-starts-from-tuesday

Comment: @learning here for mysql i think

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried (SQL) so that we may assist you better (now and in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `date_trunc` on any version.  When you truncate by week it will use Monday, but that can be resolved by adding a day so that Sunday dates roll to the next week:

```
select
  date_trunc ('week', my_date + 1)
from
  my_table
group by
  date_trunc ('week', my_date + 1)
```

When you render the final output, just be sure to subtract the day from the field (no need to do that in the group-by):

```
select
  date_trunc ('week', my_date + 1) - interval '1 day' as sunday,
  count (*)
from
  my_table
group by
  date_trunc ('week', my_date + 1)
```

If `my_date` is a timestamp (below would also work for a date), then:

```
date_trunc ('week', my_date + interval '1 day')
```

instead of:

```
date_trunc ('week', my_date + 1)
```

You can also encapsulate this into a function, but it seems overkill unless you are using this all over the place.

```
create or replace function sunday(input_date date)
returns date
language sql
as
$BODY$
  select (date_trunc ('week', input_date + 1) - interval '1 day')::date
$BODY$

select
  sunday(my_date), count (*)
from
  my_table
group by
  sunday(my_date)
```

Comment: Amm but how in pgsql make `my_date + 1` because `operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer`

Comment: Oh, it's a timestamp and not a date...  in that case `my_date + interval '1 day'`.  I'll update...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Use [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function. It is available in PG version 14 and onwards.
[Here](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Pre-PG14-date_bin-function) is an implementation for versions prior to PG14.
An illustration:

```sql
select date_bin('1 week', d, '2022-01-02')::date as db, count(1)
from generate_series('2022-07-01'::timestamp, '2022-10-01', '1 day') as d
group by db
order by db;

/*
2022-01-02 is a Sunday

db        |count|
----------+-----+
2022-06-26|    3|
2022-07-03|    7|
2022-07-10|    7|
2022-07-17|    7|
2022-07-24|    7|
2022-07-31|    7|
2022-08-07|    7|
2022-08-14|    7|
2022-08-21|    7|
2022-08-28|    7|
2022-09-04|    7|
2022-09-11|    7|
2022-09-18|    7|
2022-09-25|    6|
*/
```